Getting TypeError: invalid BytesLike value (argument="value", value=[ ], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.1) while testing a function
Here is my github repo link:
https://github.com/Jimit1512/Lottery.
And, I'm getting the following error while trying to test whether the Raffle is open or not.
Here' the code of my test file:
const {  deployments, ethers, network } = require("hardhat")
const {developmentChains, networkConfig} = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")
const {assert, expect} = require("chai")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name) 
    ? describe.skip 
    : describe("Raffle", async ()=> {
        let raffle, VRFCoordinatorV2Mock, raffleEntranceFee, deployer, interval
        const chainId = network.config.chainId

        beforeEach(async ()=> {
            const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
            deployer = accounts[0]
            await deployments.fixture(["all"])
            const raffleDeployement = await deployments.get("Raffle")
            raffle = await ethers.getContractAt("Raffle", raffleDeployement.address, deployer)
            const VRFCoordinatorV2MockDeployment = await deployments.get("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
            VRFCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", VRFCoordinatorV2MockDeployment.address)
            
            raffleEntranceFee = await raffle.getEntranceFee()
            interval = await raffle.getInterval()

        })
        describe("constructor", async () => {
            it("initializes the raffle correctly", async () => {
                const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState()
                assert.equal(raffleState.toString(), "0")
                assert.equal(interval.toString(), "1")
            })
        })

        describe("enterRaffle", async () => {
            it("Reverts when doesn't pay enough", async () => {
                await expect(raffle.enterRaffle()).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(raffle,"Raffle__SendMoreToEnterRaffle")
            })
            it("records playes when entered", async () => {
                await raffle.enterRaffle({value: raffleEntranceFee})
                const playerFromContract = await raffle.getPlayer(0)
                assert.equal(playerFromContract, deployer.address)
            })
            it("emit events on enter", async () =>{
                await expect(raffle.enterRaffle({value: raffleEntranceFee})).to.emit(raffle, "RaffleEnter")
            })
            it("doesn't allow entrance when raffle is calculating", async () => {
                await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                await network.provider.send("evm_increaseTime", [Number(interval.toString()) + 1]);
                await network.provider.send("evm_mine", [])
                
                await raffle.performUpkeep([]);                
                await expect(raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })).to.be.revertedWith("Raffle__NotOpen");
            });
        })
    })

While executing the tests using npx hardhat test command, I'm getting the following error:
 Raffle
    constructor
      ✔ initializes the raffle correctly
    enterRaffle
      ✔ Reverts when doesn't pay enough (42ms)
      ✔ records playes when entered
      ✔ emit events on enter
      1) doesn't allow entrance when raffle is calculating


  4 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Raffle
       enterRaffle
         doesn't allow entrance when raffle is calculating:
     TypeError: invalid BytesLike value (argument="value", value=[  ], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.13.1)
      at makeError (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:687:21)
      at assert (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:715:25)
      at assertArgument (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:727:5)
      at _getBytes (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\data.ts:44:19)
      at getBytesCopy (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\data.ts:66:12)
      at BytesCoder.encode (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\coders\bytes.ts:21:29)
      at D:\JIMIT JEE\New folder\Solidity\Lottery\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\coders\array.ts:55:19
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at pack (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\coders\array.ts:47:12)
      at TupleCoder.encode (node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\coders\tuple.ts:62:20)


You're facing that error because the performUpkeep function expects an argument of type bytes.
In order to pass empty bytes, you've to pass 0x instead of [] in the argument while calling the performUpkeep function in your "doesn't allow entrance when raffle is calculating" test.
So, replace:
await raffle.performUpkeep([]);

with:
await raffle.performUpkeep('0x');


Have done the changes and now giving me following error                                          Error:  VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'InvalidConsumer()'     at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.onlyValidConsumer (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:92)
at VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.requestRandomWords (@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol:165)
at Raffle.performUpkeep (contracts/Raffle.sol:120)

You need to call addConsumer() of the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract by passing in the address of your raffle contract.

Which exact tutorial are you following?

I am following Patrick Collins full stack in solidity from free code camp

Okay. Is your problem fixed after adding the call to addConsumer() of VRFCoordinatorV2Mock? If not, then please feel free to open a new question, I’ll be happy to assist.
